# How to write to the second line of a display?

Tags: display

I got this 4 line display from Mouser: https://www.gravitech.us/20chbllcd.html, and I get it to work fine for lines 1 and 3 (as line 3 is just the 21st character of line 1). But I am struggling to get lines 2 and 4 working. If I understand correctly, these are "line 2" for the HD44780 controller, and I should set the DDRAM address to `0x40` before I write there.

But, when I try that, nothing happens.

I tried writing `0x04` to the DDRAM address counter, and I can see the cursor jumping there, but when I write to that address, no text shows up. If I omit the command, text pops up correctly.

Also, when changing the contrast of the display (using the potentiometer on the Vdd and Vo pins), only lines 1 and 3 change contrast.

My code:

This method I use for convenience:

```
void set(int _rs, int _rw, int _d7, int _d6, int _d5, int _d4, int _d3, int _d2, int _d1, int _d0) { ... }
```

To set the DDRAM address to `0x40`:

```
set(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

The general timing and control is correct, as I can get text on the display, and also a function like "shift" works fine.

Comment: You're not using the standard LiquidCrystal.h library?

Comment: @Majenko no, not yet. If I cannot get this to work myself, I'll try and see if that can work. I looked at the `LiquidCrystal` source code though, and I didn't see anything I could use.

Comment: Personally I would *start* with the known working, well tested, and properly supported LiquidCrystal.h library, and then pare it down to just the code I needed (if code size were an issue). As it is we can't really help you since we don't know your code or setup.

Answer (score 1):

- Line 1 starts at address 0x00 | 0x80 `0b10000000` and ends at 0x13 | 0x80 `0b10010011`
- Line 2 starts at address 0x40 | 0x80 `0b11000000` and ends at 0x53 | 0x80 `0b11010011`
- Line 3 starts at address 0x14 | 0x80 `0b10010100` and ends at 0x27 | 0x80 `0b10100111`
- Line 4 starts at address 0x54 | 0x80 `0b11010100` and ends at 0x67 | 0x80 `0b11100111`

That 0x80 `0b10000000`  is the HD44780 command for set DDRAM address. The other bits `0b1xxxxxx` define the address.

[image: 20x4 HD44780 addressing]

You'll find more details at [Arduino with HD44780 based Character LCDs](http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-with-hd44780-based-lcds/)

Comment: Yes. That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the HD44780 in 2-line mode. The command is `| 0 | 0 | 1 | DL | N | F | X | X |` with:

- DL: 0 = 4-bit / 1 = 8-bit interface
- N: 0 = 1 line / 1 = 2 lines **(this is the bit to set)**
- F: 0 = 5x7 / 1 = 5x10 font size

Most probably you have that command already in your program to set the width of the interface, but with N = 0.

*Note: The common algorithm is to send the command `0x33` three times to make sure to be in 8-bit mode. The first can be the second part of a half-done 4-bit command, possibly not changing the interface width. Then the second and third will switch into 8-bit mode. If the device is already in 8-bit mode, or gets into it in the course, it makes no harm to repeat.*

Since in 4-bit mode only D7 to D4 are used, you can change `0x33` into `0x38` to enable the 2-lines mode.